# it is possible to find out on which line of the input field is not a match per regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

here is my regex

```
/([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2})/gm
```

and when in my input field is this

```
09/09
03/65
0938
05/37
```

I want to do an alert with something like this: there is an error in the third line

it is possible somehow?

Comment: you could split by linebreaks then check each line, if a line breaks you can know where the error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the value by new line and check each line against regex pattern.

For example:

```
        var regex = /^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}$/;
        var lines = val.split(/\r?\n/);
        for(var i = 0; i<lines.length ; i++){
            if (lines[i].match(regex) == null) {
                alert('there is an error in the ' + (i + 1) + ' line');
                break;
            }
        }
```

Note: Use `^`(beginning of the line) and `$`(end of the line) to match the whole line.